# WiX: getting Bootstrapper filname during installation

Tags: wix

our company is using WiX to create our (currently pretty simple) setup. We have a bootstrapper project which installs the .Net 4.0 Framework and runs our MSI package (WiX setup project). We now want to access the filename of the bootstrapper (Setup.exe) during runtime and save it to a file. Just for background: The filename is not fixed and will be changed by our download server frequently, so we have to access it during runtime.

Unfortunately I didn't find any solution to accomplish this with WiX. Can someone help me? Maybe you have some ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is your own bootstrapper, right? If so, the bootstrapper either knows its own name, or can detect it at runtime (`::GetModuleFileName()`). When the bootstrapper runs the **.msi** install, have it pass its name as a public property on the command line:

```
msiexec /i OurPackage.msi IWASBOOTSTRAPPEDBY=bootstrappername.exe
```

The property `IWASBOOTSTRAPPEDBY` is then available to the WiX-based **.msi** package to do with as it pleases.

For that matter, the bootstrapper program *itself* could write its name to a text file, and not even bother the **.msi** package with the task.

Comment: No it's not my own bootstrapper application. We currently use the WiX default Bootstrapper project. I hoped, that there is some built-in variable or something similar.

Comment: Ah. No, I don't think WiX **burn** does that. Since it's open source, you could of course create your own custom build of it that does. Or have your download servers dispense, instead of the setup.exe, a self-extracting archive that *contains* setup.exe but first runs a script or something to inspect its own invocation name. But no, WiX doesn't provide that for free AFAIK.

Comment: The idea with the SFX is a good hint. Anyway we took a completely different approach to solve our problem, which is independent to WiX.